Confusion in Proof for Breadth First Search Finding Shortest Path in CLRS
I am reading CLRS (https://pd.daffodilvarsity.edu.bd/course/material/book-430/pdf_content), and stuck on the proof of Theorem 22.5 - Correctness of Breadth First Search on Page 600.
The author is trying to prove that for every vertex  reachable from source  in the graph, BFS sets . = δ(, ), where . is the shortest distance found by BFS for  and δ(, ) is the shortest distance from  to . But a step in the proof assumes the above property to be true for some neighbor vertex  of , giving the reason as "because of how we chose ":



I'm sure that I am missing something here.
What is special in the way that  is chosen that allows us to assume the above mentioned property for some neighbor  of ?

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.


But a step in the proof assumes the above property to be true for some neighbor vertex u of v

Not just some neighbor of , but a neighbor that precedes  on the breadth-first path to it. Quoting the text:

Let  be the vertex immediately preceding  on a shortest path from  to , so that δ(,) = δ(,) + 1. Because δ(,) < δ(,), and because of how we chose , we have . = δ(,).

"how we chose " refers to the following:

Let  be the vertex with minimum δ(,) that receives such an incorrect  value;

The key word here is "minimum". This means that , which is closer to  than  is, cannot have an incorrect , otherwise  wasn't the minimum one. So we trust . to be δ(,).
